# Running HiveQL with Spark-SQL: how to make Hive assembly jar present on each worker node

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run HiveQL with Spark-SQL according to the section **Hive Tables** in the link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html

In this section, it says that after the Spark binary is built with the Hive option, that

> "This command builds a new assembly jar that includes Hive. Note that this Hive assembly jar must also be present on all of the worker nodes, as they will need access to the Hive serialization and deserialization libraries (SerDes) in order to access data stored in Hive."

I am not so clear about where to find this Hive assembly jar, what the name of this assembly jar is, and how to make this jar present on all of the worker nodes.

Thanks in advance if anyone can offer some help or give some hints.

Comment: Are you working on a cluster or locally?

Comment: in a cluster with several nodes, thats why i asked

Comment: If you use pre-built version of Spark it already contains all you need. If you [build Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) by yourself you should you should include [`-Phive` and `-Phive-thriftserver` flags](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support).

Comment: of course I built in the way u mentioned, even though problem came out. It must be related to the hint "Hive assembly jar must be present on all nodes". I do not know which jar exactly, and how to make this jar present on all nodes